# How to get days and hours until X in ANSI C

Tags: c, date, time, ansi-c

In C, i'm trying to get the number of days and hours until 'next tuesday, 10 am'. I don't have an exact date because this is a recurring event.

So this is what I would want:

Next tuesday 10am = 3 days and 4 hours away.

Comment: A [good C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) might come handy, note the section about [date and time utilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono).

Comment: Even with a good book or reference, it isn't entirely obvious how to go about the calculation, unless you've spent time messing with calendrical calculations.  At 06:00 on Tuesday, is 'next Tuesday at 10:00' all of 7 days and 4 hours ahead, or just 4 hours ahead? It depends on whether that is 'next Tuesday' (and a time which happens to be 10:00) or 'the next occurrence of Tuesday at 10:00'. Presumably, at 16:00 on Tuesday, the next time is 6 days 18 hours ahead.  Using standard C, you need to use `time()`, `localtime()`, `mktime()`, and maybe `difftime()` — I think.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Get current weekday.
Example:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time(&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
```

Now you have the current weekday in `timeinfo->tm_wday`, as value from 0 to 6.

Step 2:
Calculate the difference of weekdays and multiply by 24, add/subtract the difference of hours, modulo divide by 24 to get the days.
or
Fill another `struct tm`, calculating the future date using the information you have (means you need to take care when wrapping a month or year) and the current time. Use this struct tm to calculate the `difftime()`, convert the resulting seconds into days and hours.